# How do I redirect to a Cmis folder?

Tags: java, zk, workbench, cmis, zul

I'm new in this field and now working with Zk framework. In my website I have a widget in the dashboard which should allows the user to see their favorite content, and a link to go directly to the Favorites folder.

The Favorites folder doesn't have a different URL than the dashboard so I can't write a URL after href.

```
<div id="dashboardWidgetContent" class="favourites-container">
     <h:div class="favourites-link">
        <h:a href="/favouriteQuery" class="textlink">${c:l('drive.dashboard.favourites.link')}</h:a>
     </h:div>
```

I'm using the Cmis Workbench and it just shows me that the favorite path is: /favouriteQuery

any suggestion?

Comment: if the URL doesn't support additional parameters then there's nothing you can do from the ZK side.
Searching for "Cmis Workbench" and "/favouriteQuery" doesn't really return any documentation of that endpoint, nor is it clear which "Cmis workbench" you're referring to, do you have a link to the actual Cmis server documentation, explaining what the url is supposed to do?

Comment: Thanks for your response, actually i asked the wrong question and i could solve it in java by using childrenNames = StreamSupport.stream(favouritesFolder.getChildren().spliterator(), false)
            .map(node -> node.getName()).limit(NUMBER_OF_FILES_TO_DISPLAY).collect(Collectors.toList());